# Pandas Key Error date

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, dataframe

```
df['ts'] = pd.to_datetime(df['_created_at'])
df = df.set_index('ts')

def f(x):
    x = x.reindex(df.index)
    x = x.sort_values('battery')
    x['ts'] = x['ts'].fillna(method='ffill')  
    x['battery'] = x['battery'].combine_first(df['battery'])
    x['model'] = x['model'].combine_first(df['model'])
    x['user'] = x['user'].combine_first(df['user'])
    x['version'] = x['version'].combine_first(df['version'])
    return x
```

I have the above code and it seems I run into an error when I get to the `x['ts'] = x['ts'].fillna(method='ffill')` line. This occurs when I run the following command:

`df = df.groupby(level=0, sort=False).apply(f).reset_index(level=0, drop=True).reset_index()`

My `ts` values look like : `2013-03-04 13:56:29.662` and are datetime64; I don't understand what I am doing wrong that is causing this key error on `ts` as I thought seeing them as `to_datetime` would put the index in a format pandas understands. Ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to omit this problematic row like, because column `ts` is set to `index` and is filled values by `x.reindex(df.index)`. I think you need delete column `_created_at` by [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
print df
               _created_at user  battery model  version
0  2013-03-04 13:56:29.662    R        3     A        1
1  2013-03-05 13:56:29.662    S        5     B        3
2  2013-03-06 13:56:29.662    J        6     C        2

df['ts'] = pd.to_datetime(df['_created_at'])

df = df.drop('_created_at', axis=1)

df = df.set_index(['ts'])

def f(x):
    #print x
    x = x.reindex(df.index)
    x = x.sort_values('battery')
    #x['ts'] = x['ts'].fillna(method='ffill')  
    x['battery'] = x['battery'].combine_first(df['battery'])
    x['model'] = x['model'].combine_first(df['model'])
    x['user'] = x['user'].combine_first(df['user'])
    x['version'] = x['version'].combine_first(df['version'])
    return x

df = df.groupby(level=0, sort=False).apply(f).reset_index(level=0, drop=True).reset_index()
print df
                       ts user  battery model  version
0 2013-03-04 13:56:29.662    R        3     A        1
1 2013-03-05 13:56:29.662    S        5     B        3
2 2013-03-06 13:56:29.662    J        6     C        2
3 2013-03-05 13:56:29.662    S        5     B        3
4 2013-03-04 13:56:29.662    R        3     A        1
5 2013-03-06 13:56:29.662    J        6     C        2
6 2013-03-06 13:56:29.662    J        6     C        2
7 2013-03-04 13:56:29.662    R        3     A        1
8 2013-03-05 13:56:29.662    S        5     B        3
```

But maybe you need [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) for other column e.g. `user`:

```
df['ts'] = pd.to_datetime(df['_created_at'])

df = df.drop('_created_at', axis=1)

df = df.set_index(['ts'])

def f(x):
    #print x
    x = x.reindex(df.index)
    x = x.sort_values('battery')
    #x['ts'] = x['ts'].fillna(method='ffill')
    x['battery'] = x['battery'].combine_first(df['battery'])
    x['model'] = x['model'].combine_first(df['model'])
    x['user'] = x['user'].fillna(method='ffill')  
    x['version'] = x['version'].combine_first(df['version'])
    return x

df = df.groupby(level=0, sort=False).apply(f).reset_index(level=0, drop=True).reset_index()
print df
                       ts user  battery model  version
0 2013-03-04 13:56:29.662    R        3     A        1
1 2013-03-05 13:56:29.662    R        5     B        3
2 2013-03-06 13:56:29.662    R        6     C        2
3 2013-03-05 13:56:29.662    S        5     B        3
4 2013-03-04 13:56:29.662    S        3     A        1
5 2013-03-06 13:56:29.662    S        6     C        2
6 2013-03-06 13:56:29.662    J        6     C        2
7 2013-03-04 13:56:29.662    J        3     A        1
8 2013-03-05 13:56:29.662    J        5     B        3
```